# Improper integral convergence check

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to find all $\alpha$ when this integral converges:

$$\int\limits_0^{+ \infty }\frac{(x^ \alpha+x)dx }{e^x \operatorname{arctg}x}$$

at $0+$: $\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x \operatorname{arctg}x}\sim \frac{x^\alpha + x}{(1+x)x} \sim \frac{x^\alpha + x}{(1+x)x} \sim x^{\alpha-2} $ I use here: $\operatorname{arctg}x \sim x, e^x=1+x$

at $\infty$: $ \operatorname{arctg}x = \pi/2$, and then I have $\frac {x^{\alpha}+x}{e^x}$.

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $0^+,~$ $e^x\sim 1, ~\arctan(x)\sim x$

$$\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x \arctan(x)}\sim \frac{x^\alpha + x}{x} \sim \frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}+1 \Rightarrow 1-\alpha<1\Rightarrow \alpha>0$$

At $\infty,~$ $ \arctan(x)\sim \frac{\pi}2$, and the integral converges for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, because:

$$\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x \arctan(x)}\sim \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x} \Rightarrow \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$$

So we have $$\alpha>0\cap\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \alpha>0$$

Comment: Could we prove that the integral goes through a minimum value for $\alpha \sim \frac 76$ ? This would be interesting. Cheers :-)

Comment: As I understand the integral converges always at $\infty$. How do you get it? I mean $ \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x} \Rightarrow \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Do you use L'Hôpital's rule to prove $\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{x^\alpha + x}{e^x} \Rightarrow \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$